# How to disable stm32f405 jtag interface

Tags: stm32

I have a board using STM32F405RG, my client designed the hardware and had to use a couple of the JTAG pins (PA15 and PB4) as GPIO. I use SWD for flashing and debug so I would like to disable the JTAG interface and, as stated in the ST docs, "release" PA15 and PB4 to be used as GPIO outputs.

Most of my searches return how to disable the JTAG interface refer to the STM32F1xx and the F4 is much different in this area.

Since with PA15 and PB4 the AFR setting of zero selects the JTAG pin functions how does one release them to be used as GPIO outputs?

Comment: STMCubeMX can help you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's true that F1 JTAG port settings are different from F4 series.

**In F1 series**, you need to disable them from *AF remap and debug I/O configuration register*. For example, the following code disables JTAG pins but leaves SWD enabled:

```
RCC->APB2ENR |= RCC_APB2ENR_AFIOEN; // Enable A.F. clock
AFIO->MAPR |= AFIO_MAPR_SWJ_CFG_JTAGDISABLE; // JTAG is disabled, SWD is enabled
```

**In F4 series** it's easier. It's true that AF 0 selects JTAG pins but all you have to do is not selecting AF in MODER registers. On power-up, PA13, PA14, PA15, PB3 & PB4 are set to alternate function mode by their corresponding MODER bits. Just select another mode (input, output or analog) for those pins using the MODER registers.

Answer (score 0):

You have to as you said `"release" PA15 and PB4 to be used as GPIO outputs.`

I don't think the F1 and F4 are different in this matter. So you configure them as outputs and set them forced high or low. This will disable their ability to be driven by the JTAG adapter